# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: InprogressFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

When I click on order menu the app suddenly stopped working, and on the log show this error
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQX1B.png), it says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: InprogressFragment`
I have 2 section pager on order menu, it's for inprogress & pastOrders.
here is the code

inProgressFragment:

```
class InprogressFragment : Fragment(), InprogressAdapter.ItemAdapterCallback {
        
        private var adapter: InprogressAdapter? = null
        private var inprogressList: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()
        
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inprogress, container, false)
        }
    
        override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    
            inprogressList = arguments?.getParcelableArrayList("data")
    
            if (!inprogressList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                adapter = InprogressAdapter(inprogressList!!, this)
                val layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                rvList.layoutManager = layoutManager
                rvList.adapter = adapter
            }
    
        }
    
        override fun onClick(v: View?, data: Data) {
            val detail = Intent(activity, OrdersDetailActivity::class.java).putExtra("data", data)
            startActivity(detail)
        }
    }
```

OrderFragment:

```
 class OrderFragment : Fragment(), OrderContract.View{
    
        lateinit var presenter: OrderPresenter
        var progressDialog: Dialog? = null

    private var inprogressList: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()
    private var pastordersList: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        initView()
        presenter = OrderPresenter(this)
        presenter.getTransaction()
    }

    override fun onTransactionSuccess(transactionResponse: TransactionResponse) {

        Log.v("tamvan", "ini token "+IcaCraft.getApp().getToken())

        if (transactionResponse.data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            include_toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
            ll_tab.visibility = View.GONE
            ll_empty.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        } else {

            for (a in transactionResponse.data.indices) {
                // past order
                if (transactionResponse.data[a].status.equals("ON_DELIVERY", true)
                    || transactionResponse.data[a].status.equals("PENDING", true)) {
                    inprogressList?.add(transactionResponse.data[a])
                    // progress
                } else if (transactionResponse.data[a].status.equals("DELIVERY", true)
                    || transactionResponse.data[a].status.equals("DELIVERED", true)
                    || transactionResponse.data[a].status.equals("CANCELLED", true)
                    || transactionResponse.data[a].status.equals("SUCCESS", true)) {
                    pastordersList?.add(transactionResponse.data[a])
                }
            }

            if (inprogressList.isNullOrEmpty() && pastordersList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                include_toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
                ll_tab.visibility = View.GONE
                ll_empty.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    childFragmentManager
                )
                sectionsPagerAdapter.setData(inprogressList, pastordersList)
                //viewPager!!.offscreenPageLimit = 3
                viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onTransactionFailed(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        progressDialog = Dialog(requireContext())
        val dialogLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loader, null)

        progressDialog?.let {
            it.setContentView(dialogLayout)
            it.setCancelable(false)
            it.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
        }

        include_toolbar.toolbar.title = "Your Orders"
        include_toolbar.toolbar.subtitle = "Wait for the best meal"
    }

    override fun showLoading() {
        progressDialog?.show()
    }

    override fun dismissLoading() {
        progressDialog?.dismiss()
    }
}
```

SectionPagerAdapter:

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) :
    FragmentPagerAdapter(
        fm
    ) {

    var inprogressList: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()
    var pastOrdersList: ArrayList<Data>? = ArrayList()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {

        var fragment : Fragment
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                    fragment = InprogressFragment()
                    val bundle = Bundle()
                    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", inprogressList)
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle)
                    return fragment
            }
            1 -> {
                    fragment = PastordersFragment()
                    val bundle = Bundle()
                    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", pastOrdersList)
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle)
                    return fragment
                }
            else -> {
                fragment = InprogressFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", inprogressList)
                fragment.setArguments(bundle)
                return fragment
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> "In Progress"
            1 -> "Past Orders"
            else -> null
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

    fun setData(inprogressListParms: ArrayList<Data>?, pastOrdersListParms: ArrayList<Data>?) {
        inprogressList = inprogressListParms
        pastOrdersList = pastOrdersListParms
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter , avoid getting fragment by position, and pass list with the count of items for Fragment and make getPageTitle from list of titles like here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: I am sorry but I really new on this android studio, can you help me step by step please?

Comment: Also, read the official documentation and try to make sample codelabs it will help you to deeply understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this(I didn't test this code, it's just a concept for your app):

```
enum class FragmentType {
    IN_PROGRESS,
    POSTORDERS
}

data class Data(
    val fragmentType: FragmentType,
    val fragmentName: String,
    val orderList: ArrayList<Data>?
)

class SectionsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    var inprogressList: ArrayList<Data> = ArrayList()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        val item = inprogressList[position]
        return when (item.fragmentType) {
            FragmentType.IN_PROGRESS -> {
                InprogressFragment().apply {
                    val bundle = Bundle()
                    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", item.orderList)
                    setArguments(bundle)
                }
            }
            FragmentType.POSTORDERS -> {
                PastordersFragment().apply {
                    val bundle = Bundle()
                    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", item.orderList)
                    setArguments(bundle)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return inprogressList[position].fragmentName
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return inprogressList.size
    }

    fun setData(items: ArrayList<Data>) {
        inprogressList = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```